# What exactly does $\frac{\partial(y_1,\dots,y_m)}{\partial(x_1,\dots,x_n)}$ refer to?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation

I have been asking a rather few questions of this nature lately, maybe I'm starting to realise math notation isn't as uniform as I initially thought it would be...

Question: Does this notation
$$\frac{\partial(y_1,\dots,y_m)}{\partial(x_1,\dots,x_n)}$$
refer to the Jacobian *matrix*
$$ J = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \dfrac{\partial y_m}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial y_m}{\partial x_n}  \end{bmatrix},$$
or the Jacobian *determinant* $\det J$?

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14952/what-is-jacobian-matrix/14955#14955) seems to support the latter interpretation, while [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34010/find-the-jacobian/34024#34024]) (and Wikipedia) both support the former.

I am aware of the ambiguity of "Jacobian" being used to refer to either the determinant or the matrix itself, is this a similar case? It's really a bit annoying because when I see things like
$$ \left| \frac{\partial(y_1,\dots,y_m)}{\partial(x_1,\dots,x_n)} \right| $$
I don't know if it means the absolute value of the Jacobian determinant, or the determinant of the Jacobian matrix.

Comment: It's the matrix; that being said, $\left| \frac{\partial(y_1,\dots,y_m)}{\partial(x_1,\dots,x_n)} \right|$ is very unfortunate notation; I'd use $\det$ myself if I have to talk about the determinant in this context...

Comment: Wolfram MathWorld seems confused as to what exactly the notation means too. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Jacobian.html, equations (4), (7) and (10).

Comment: Well at the very least, I see that equation three there uses brackets and not vertical bars...

Comment: I'd say it's the matrix, whereas $\frac{d(y_1,\dots,y_m)}{d(x_1,\dots,x_n)}$ is the determinant.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Do Carmo uses it as Jacobian determinant in his book on Riemannian geometry.

Comment: I would say determinant.  But we see here it is ambiguous, so you should say what you mean when you use it.

Comment: @Hans: So the one with $\partial$ is the matrix while the one with $d$ is the determinant? \*Goes woozy\*

Comment: @GEdgar: Yeah I can see it's really ambiguous.. Just wanted to know which was the more common interpretation, if any. Thanks :)

Comment: To see which is more common, find it in a few textbooks.  (Not Wikipedia.)  I know of no textbook that has the notation mentioned by Hans.

Comment: @GEdgar: Funny. That notation is what I learned from a standard Swedish calculus book long ago, and I've never given it much thought since then. Maybe it's a local thing. I see now that Rudin's *Principles*, for example, uses $\partial$ for the determinant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time that I use it and have seen it, I have used it to refer to the matrix itself. I will typically use det J to refer to the determinant, but I admit that I have used the term Jacobian to refer to both the matrix and the determinant.

This is another case where math is precise, but the language of math is often not. I would recommend that you take care to be specific in your usage - use Jacobian matrix and Jacobian determinant so that there is no confusion.

Comment: Yes, I agree with using the specific phrases "Jacobian matrix" and "Jacobian determinant", but with regard to the "partial" notation? I suppose I should just state what I mean it to be at the outset?