# Jacobian in Levenberg-Marquardt for 4-Parameter equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, algorithms, derivatives, optimization, regression

I am trying to fully understand how I can use Levenberg-Marquardt to minimise a 4 parameter equation.  There are lots of fancy programs to do this but the documentation about the mathematics is confusing to me. I would really like to understand what is going on to obtain an answer.

My equation is of the form:
$$ x = p_2 * [\frac{2p_1 + p_4 - y}{y - p_1}]^{(1/p_3)} $$
where $p_1$ to $p_4$ are the parameters to be minimised (initial guesses used for them).  $x$ is known and $y$ is measured.

From what I have read (in particular Numerical Optimization by Nocedal and Wright) I understand the Jacobian used in the algorithm to be the derivative of residuals. The residuals being: known $x$ - $x$ calculated, using $p$ values and $y$ values.

I want to ensure that my Jacobian format is correct. At the moment say I have 10 $x$ and $y$ values. I believe my jacobian to be a 10 row * 4 column matrix, where each column represents the derivative of the function with respect to one of the variables as below, where $x$ represents the function above:

$$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial p_1} \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial p_2} \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial p_3} \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial p_4} \\\ \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial p_1} \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial p_2} \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial p_3} \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial p_4} \\\ .................. \\\ .................. \\\ \frac{\partial x_{10}}{\partial p_1} \frac{\partial x_{10}}{\partial p_2} \frac{\partial x_{10}}{\partial p_3} \frac{\partial x_{10}}{\partial p_4} \end{bmatrix}$$

Have I misinterpreted [Find the Jacobian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34010/find-the-jacobian) article or is this format correct?

Also as it is the Jacobian of residuals to be used is the equation below correct for the entry on the first row & second column?

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial p_2} = x_1 - [\frac{2p_1 + p_4 - y}{y_1 - p_1}]^{(1/p_3)}$$

Any help and guidance appreciated as I am worried I am on the wrong track entirely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realise now that I have made a basic mathematical error with this.  I now have a working Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm with the following Jacobian format:

$$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial p_1} \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial p_2} \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial p_3} \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial p_4} \\\ \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial p_1} \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial p_2} \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial p_3} \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial p_4} \\\ .................. \\\ .................. \\\ \frac{\partial x_{10}}{\partial p_1} \frac{\partial x_{10}}{\partial p_2} \frac{\partial x_{10}}{\partial p_3} \frac{\partial x_{10}}{\partial p_4} \end{bmatrix}$$

As this algorithm uses the Jacobian of residuals, and the residuals would take the form:

$$ x - p_2 * [\frac{2p_1 + p_4 - y}{y - p_1}]^{(1/p_3)} $$

Differentiating would cause the $x$ to "disappear" as it is a constant and so disappears when differentiation is performed.

So the entry on the first row and second column would be:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial p_2} = - [\frac{2p_1 + p_4 - y}{y_1 - p_1}]^{(1/p_3)}$$

My confusion stemmed from the fact that the Jacobian is referred to using many names in texts such as the negative Gradient, change in residuals and determinant of the negative Gradient.